# Is it possible to set the content level for all logical table sources?

Tags: oracle, obiee

I work regularly on an OBIEE repository with 100+ facts and 200+ logical table sources.

Every time I add a new dimension, I have to go one-by-one to set the logical level for that dimension in each and every table source.
[image]
Is there any way, when adding a dimension, to default all LTS to a specific logical level?

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as for [cross-post here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4000887):

> Is there any way, when adding a dimension, to default all LTS to a specific logical level?

No.

A model this size is probably not the best approach in an ideal world.

The only option you have is to look at a script-based approach. There is a [supported API for modifying the RPD metadata](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIEIT/bi_server_web_services.htm#BIEIT3253), (and [here too](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/biee/BIEXR/xml_about.htm#BIEXR3428)), but it'd be pretty easy to screw things up, doubly so given the size and complexity of your existing RPD.
You can see an example of it in action in [a blog I wrote here](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2015/09/using-the-bi-server-metadata-web-service-for-automated-rpd-modifications/). Note that all I change in that blog post is the value of an existing repository variable. To add in additional content, with the issue of GUIDs etc, gets very hairy indeed.

**tl;dr** : sit tight, and keep clicking, unless you're feeling brave